# Accidental voting

Tags: support, voting

I didn't mean to vote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063497/hidden-features-of-erlang/1086640#1086640) but have accidently clicked 'vote up'. Then I clicked 'vote down' to undo previous vote. I think it doesn't do what I expected, it just adds 10 and then subtracts 2 from reputation of one who gave the answer, and subtracts 1 from voter's reputation. Is there any way to undo such actions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you accidentally click an upvote, click again to remove it. Same for a downvote.

Clicking a downvote (after clicking an upvote) will remove your upvote and issue a downvote instead.

Comment: You however need to be on time. After 5 minutes it's locked until he (or someone else) edits the post.

Comment: Daaaaaaaaaaaamn

Comment: @Yasir: I have edited the answer. You should now be able to remove the downvote. Just click the orange arrow once again.

Comment: @Josh: So clicking upvote then clicking downvote is the same as clicking upvote then clicking it again to undo and eventually clicking downvote? Also it turns out the same [person](http://stackoverflow.com/users/35448/bjnortier) gave two answer, thus accident seems to occur with both answers. I'm sorry for inconvencies, probably I'm to tired to use SO today.

Comment: @Yasir: That's correct. Clicking the other arrow immediately will inverse the vote. Clicking the arrow once again removes it.

Comment: @BaluS: Yes, I've removed a downvote from the answer beginning 'Parameterized Modules! From..'.

Comment: @Yasir: I edited the other answer as well. You can now remove your second accidental downvote. In the future, watch out! And remember, click the orange arrow once again to remove it ;)

Comment: @BalusC: probably I did that because of pictures being disabled in browser :) Thanks.